Validate user string input inside the Discord.js SlashCommandBuilder
I have added a StringOption to a slash command in my Discord.js bot that I wish to validate before the command is sent.
I can limit the length of the string with .setMaxLength() and .setMinLength()  but I would like to further restrict what can be input.
There are too many valid entries (approximately 600) to use Choices and I would prefer not to break it up and add several Required Options to an already Option-heavy Command.
Is there a way to validate user string input (perhaps using RegEx) inside the SlashCommandBuilder or is my only option to wait until the command is sent and reply with a message saying their input was invalid?

Since the maximum amount of choices possible with SlashCommandBuilder is 25, you can use the Autocomplete function to only auto complete valid options.

I am looking into it and so far it seems like autocomplete needs a list of Choices.  Is there a way I can compare the input to a Regular Expression or something?

There is no way to perform RegEx validation before your bot gets the reply. I'm not sure what kind of choices the user is selecting from, but your best option would be to perform all RegEx validation on the bots side and possibly provide Autocomplete suggestions for some possible choices?

AutoComplete is the right answer here.  Since you said you have 600 choices, your code is going to do something about these 600 options anyway.  This list of choices can be stored, and served (say in alphabetical order, or however you want to present), and then you "filter" the responses inside the AutoComplete handler, based on what the user starts typing.  This way it refines the list as they go.  This is done before the "command" handler executes, so the command handler will now receive a "syntax checked" string (from the AutoComplete handler), before it, itself begins.
